Shelly get voltage
I am struggeling to get the current voltage out of Shelly via script.
I added an event, whenever the power changes, the current voltage should be printed. But result is always undefined.
Shelly.addEventHandler(
  function(apower_change,ud){
    
    print('Power: ' + apower_change.info.apower);
    
    Shelly.call("Voltmeter.GetStatus",{id: 0},
      function(result,error_code,error_message,ud){
        print(result);
      },null
    );
  },null
);


see this

and this

This worked.
"Voltmeter.GetStatus" --> "Switch.GetStatus"
Shelly.call("Switch.GetStatus",{id: 0},
  function(result,error_code,error_message,ud){
    print(result.voltage);
  },null
);

